# How to add a source file on Contiki's Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, contiki

I am using the source file from https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki I added a new directory (say `/foo`) that includes some .c and .h files

I need to use them on `examples/cc26xx` , although I included the .h files (under `/foo`) to cc26xx-demo.c, it doesn't really include the files when I run `make`

can anyone tell me how do I need to include them either on [examples/cc26xx/Makefile](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/cc26xx/Makefile) or [Makefile.include](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/Makefile.include)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

adding     `PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += mylib.c` to Makefile solved the issue.